# Change title of page in smarty

Tags: smarty, title

I need to change the title of my home page in smarty. I'm cannot figure out how to do this.

My header.tpl code reads:

`

```
<title>{$title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{$desc}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords}">
```

....

I know that I need to target {$title} for my home page, which is home_logged_out.tpl...but I'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: you probably have a header.php file somewhere else that sets all the smarty vars.  alternatively you could just put your title in place of {$title}

Comment: in your home controller add the parameter title...